# What am I doing wrong in this powerbi Formula

Tags: powerbi, formula, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have done an analysis which consists of total distinct claims in one column and then 2nd column consists of all the claims excluding "rejected" claims. The 3rd column consists of all the claims excluding "withdrawn" claims.

Both these rejected and withdrawn are the values of a column in my table called [milestone flag].

The 4th column consists of all the claims excluding "100% cash settled" which is  a part of different column called [cash settlement flag].The 5th column should give me the total of all the claims excluding "rejected, withdrawn and 100% cash". I have used the formula Total volume for

```
Conversion = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[full_claim_number]),
    Sheet1[milestone_status] IN {"Finalised", "Outstanding", "Closed"}, Sheet1[Cash Settlement Claim Flag] IN {"No Cash Settlement", "Cash Settlement - Partial"}
)
```

But then there are few claims which are **rejected and 100% cash settled** or **withdrawn and 100% cash settled**, so it is giving me few extra numbers in the 5th column. How do I fix this in powerbi?

Example:

| Total Claims | Claimsexcludingrejected | claimsexcludingwithdrawn | claimsexcluding100%cash | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 119 | 96 | 110 | 93 | 64 |

The total here should be 61 (excluding all the 3) but then it is showing up as 64. The 3 claims are rejected and also 100% cash settled. Hence it is showing up as 64. How can I not consider the repeated claims in total ?

Comment: I found the answer for this. 64 is the correct answer as there were few claim ids which are rejected/withdrawn and was also 100% cash settled.